Release update on LIghtning Article Editor not working
I enabled the release update "Turn On Lightning Article Editor and Article Personalization for Knowledge" in one of our sandbox and it is working fine and I am able to see the improved lightning article editor when I try to create/edit a knowledge article. However, the result is not same on a different sandbox. I enabled the same release update, but when I try to create/edit a knowledge article, I am seeing only old article editor. The sandbox where it is working is a full copy sandbox and where it is not working is a developer sandbox.
Does anyone have insights on this issue?

Have you confirmed which release your sandboxes are in? Not all environments will be on Winter '25 right now as there is still another release weekend to go.
